# DOMException Not found error

Tags: java, xml, swing, dom, jtree

I need a GUI to manipulate 2 XML docs with Drag and Drop. The XML docs need to appear in tree structure next to each other so you can easily drag elements from one doc to the other. One tree is static, and the other can be changed that means that in the dynamic tree nodes can be added or deleted. Until now the program reads the xml docs with DOM and displays them with JTrees. When I drop the Node I want to add in the dynamic tree I get this exception

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR:An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
```

The error appears in the line where insertBefore(..) is called:

```
public void insertNodeInto(AdapterNode draggedNode, AdapterNode newSisterNode) {

    Node importNode = document.importNode(draggedNode.getNode(), true);
    Node added = document.getDocumentElement().insertBefore(importNode, newSisterNode.getNode());

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but nobody will write your program for you. Try it by yourself!

Comment: *"I have made some short comments in the code."* Did you ask a *question* in the code? If so, move it to text as a (non code) part of the above by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39974812/edit). If not, think of a question and do the same (edit). SO is not a code generation machine, a place to find a tutor, or a help desk. It is a Q&A site where in this thread, there is no Q.

Comment: Is the problem that I have two Jtrees and I want to transfer data from one underlying TreeModel to the other?